# How to relocate closing tags in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know how to relocate a closing tag in the XML using XSLT. Normally everything seems to use matching to make things work, but this appears to be different.  The goal is to obtain the desired output without changing the XML file directly.  I want to create the desired output only by using the XSLT. This code below is close but it does not close the manager tag.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>
    <y>
        <z value="john" designation="manager"></z>
            <z value="mike" designation="associate"></z>
           <z value="dave" designation="associate"></z>
   </y>
</x>
```

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="x">
    <employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(@designation, 'manager')]">
    <manager>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </manager>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(@designation, 'associate')]">
    <associate>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </associate>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <manager value="john">
            <associate>mike</associate>
            <associate>dave</associate>
        </manager>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Think trees, not tags! Try drawing a tree diagram of the structure of the input and a tree diagram of the structure of the output. XSLT is all about transforming trees, not about rearranging tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not about "relocating a closing tag". It is about rearranging the hierarchy of the XML tree, by transforming siblings into parent and children. This could be accomplished as follows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="z[@designation='manager']"/>
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z[@designation='manager']">
    <manager value="{@value}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../z[@designation='associate']"/>
    </manager>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z[@designation='associate']">
    <associate>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </associate>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there will be only one manager. Otherwise all associates will be listed under more than one manager.